# Conditional filtering in Mule Dataweave %1.0

Tags: json, mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am trying to filter a particular value coming from a JSON array. My sample array is given below:

```
"source":[
  {
    "value": {
      "Type": [
        {
          "val": "Primary",
          "code": "PRI"
        }
      ],
      "Value": [
        {
          "val": "PHAR",
          "Code": "Pharmacy"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "value": {
      "Type": [
        {
          "val": "Secondary",
          "code": "SEC"
        }
      ],
      "Value": [
        {
          "val": "HOSP",
          "Code": "Hospital"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

---

In the above, I need to read the first occurrence of **source.value.Value.val** where **source.value.Type.code=="SEC"**
My array can have multiple codes like "PRI", "SEC" etc and I need to get the data for code = "SEC" only (first occurance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the filter function to filter your array.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
 output: payload.source filter ($.value.Type[0].code == "SEC")

}
```

the above code will produce the following output:

```
{
  "output": [
    {
      "value": {
        "Type": [
          {
            "val": "Secondary",
            "code": "SEC"
          }
        ],
        "Value": [
          {
            "val": "HOSP",
            "Code": "Hospital"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Amendment**: Here is the new piece of code which will give you only the value you are looking for and not the whole Array

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
{
    (payload.source default [] map (source, indexOfSource) -> {
        output: source.value.Value[0].val when source.value.Type[0].code == "SEC" otherwise null
    }) 
}
```

The output of the above piece of code is:

```
{
  "output": "HOSP"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Satish. The value that I am looking at is not an array. It should be a string, something like: CustomValue: HOSP

Comment: @TriumphSpitfire i have updated my answer as per your need. check please

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped!